# Numa Node configuration for SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, cpu, numa

I have a question on one of my new build sql servers where we are planning to migrate our SQL databases from older SQL2012 running on windows 2012.

New build- SQL2016 on Windows 2016

My current [SQL2012]==> When querying os_nodes dmv shows what i am assuming as 4 numa nodes config with memory `node id`=0,1,2,3 & `processor group` 0,1,0,1 and `scheduler count`= 20 for all id's

My new [SQL2016]==> When querying os_nodes dmv shows what i am assuming as 8 numa nodes config with `memory node id`=0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1 & `processor group` 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1  and `scheduler count`= 9 for all id's

Below is O/P from os_nodes dmv between old and new configured SQL servers

[image: dmv os_nodes_o/p]

Questions

> When viewed via task manger/ssms it shows 2 Numa nodes. Is my above
>   understanding wrong of 8 Numa nodes?
>
> If those are 2 Numa nodes will i have any performance impact compared
>   to current setup?

Also note `softnuma_configuration_des`c shows **ON** for sql2016

Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When viewed via task manger/ssms it shows 2 Numa nodes. Is my above understanding wrong of 8 Numa nodes?

No, SQL Server 2016 started to ship with automatic numa node partitioning (soft numa) which is what you're seeing here.

> If those are 2 Numa nodes will i have any performance impact compared to current setup?

Impossible to say. Automatic Soft-Numa was added as a default to the product starting with 2016 as certain tasks and threads are on a per-numa basis. Thus, in many environments that had high core count and low numa node count there would be an overall performance improvement by using soft-numa.

Your mileage may and will vary. If you're unsure or don't want to test the new configuration, I would suggest you turn the automatic soft-numa off for now until you can test. This is based on absolutely *no data* but configuration stabilization between upgrades.

If you want to [turn soft-numa off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-server-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you can run the following command:

`ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION SET SOFTNUMA OFF`